# CIElab colour mixing with alpha

Tags: algorithm, colors, rgb

While mixing colours in CIElab is it possible to take into account alpha channel of a one?
There is wiki page about alpha https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing but that is only about rgb.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut. You must convert to RGB, which is a linear space, perform the compositing and then back to Lab.